# Selecting An Attribute From The Clicked href

Tags: jquery

On a page I have multiple links all with a tracking code attached. The tracking code is different on every link. When I click on a link I want to select the tracking code attached to that href. If I just use

```
$('.bannerLink').attr('data-trackingcode')
```

It'll just select the first link rather than the one I click on. How do I select the one I just clicked on

```
<div class="container">
<div>
<a href="someLink" class="bannerLink" data-trackingcode="trackingCodeA">
<img src="//someImage.jpg" alt="Cereals">
</a></div></div>

<div class="container">
<div>
<a href="someLink" class="bannerLink" data-trackingcode="trackingCodeB">
<img src="//someImage.jpg" alt="Cereals">
</a></div></div>

<div class="container">
<div>
<a href="someLink" class="bannerLink" data-trackingcode="trackingCodeC">
<img src="//someImage.jpg" alt="Cereals">
</a></div></div>
```

Comment: You have no elements with the attribute `'data-trackingcode'`. You should be using data attributes like `<a href="someLink" class="bannerLink" data-trackingcode="trackingCodeA">` and retrieve it with `$('.bannerLink').data('trackingcode')` or `$(this).data('trackingcode')`. You also forgot to post your jQuery.

Comment: Second the use `data()` for accessing `data-*` attributes mentioned by Rory below. Would also be helpful if you posted your original attempt so people point out fixes specific to your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked element within the click event handler function. Try this:

```
$('.bannerLink').click(function() {
    var trackingCode = $(this).data('trackingcode');
});
```

Note the use of `data()` to access the `data-*` attribute is preferred over `attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.bannerLink',function() {
    $(this).attr('trackingcode')
});
```